# Get UTC offset from TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I am making an app for ios using Xamarin, which is used all over the world(US, Europe and Africa for now).

This app sends registered data to the server, and the users want to see the the time of the data localized to registration.

So I figured I would store the DateTime.UtcNow in the database, together with the timezone name, so I used TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName, and thought I would use these two fields to be able to display the utc datetime localized to the timezone, but I am having some problems.

How can I get timezone offset from this "StandardName", these are some of the values I am getting from Xamarin on iOS: "CET", "WAT"(Congo I think), "EST" and "+0545" (What is this???)

OR, should I store the offset instead, which I assume should be easy to get on each device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to store the time zone ID, store `TimeZoneInfo.Id`, not `StandardName`. I'd expect time zone IDs on any Unix-based system to look like "Europe/London" etc. (This is the [IANA time zone](http://iana.org/tz) ID format.)

You should then be able to get the time zone back again using [`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.findsystemtimezonebyid). But note that that *won't* work if you try to get a time zone by an IANA ID on Windows, or a time zone by a Windows ID on Unix. If that's a problem, you might want to consider using a consistent time zone database everywhere, potentially using my [Noda Time project](https://nodatime.org) which ships with an IANA database included in it. You could then use that on both Unix and Windows machines.

Storing an offset instead would be okay if it's for a current or past event. Storing it for a *future* event is risky, because it means you can't take action if time zone rules change. Even storing a UTC value and time zone ID can be risky there, too: if you want to represent "9am in Paris on February 1st 2025" then you probably want to store *exactly that* information rather than "The UTC instant that I'm currently predicting will map to 9am in Paris".

Comment: Thank you! I'll store the date as UTC, and a separate column for UTC offset(integer holding minutes then I guess) since this is strictly past events. I will probably also store the Timezone Id and just display it as is together with "local time".

Comment: Just a comment on "TimeZoneInfo.Id", for "TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id" running Xamarin on an iPad this is "Local", so not of much use... I had to use iOS TimeZone object like this to get the IANA string: NSTimeZone.LocalTimeZone.Name. I guess I should report this as an xamarin bug...

Comment: @Tompi: Ah yes, I remember now that some Xamarin environments are pretty poor for `TimeZoneInfo.Local`. In Noda Time, we try to work out the time zone based on its offsets at various points in recent history.